# How to calculate numerically the integral of 1/(√x·(x+1));

Tags: matlab

Here is a function handler to the function of interest:

```
fun = @(x) 1 / (sqrt(x) * (x + 1));

q = integral(fun, 0, inf)
```

But I got the following error:

```
 Error using  * 
    Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You could also use [the exact solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+1%2F(sqrt(x)*(x%2B1))): the answer is π.

Comment: Perhaps, it should be firstly noted that function `fun` will be used to generate an array of values, so it needs a _vectorised input_. The error is due to assumed vectorised input which leads to `*` being interpreted as _dot product_ (matrix multiplication: row by column) rather than simple (element-by-element) multiplication.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use `.` periods when defining an element-wise operation rather than matrix operations. This is needed for the `integral` function inputs.

Your function should be

```
fun = @(x) 1./(sqrt(x).*(x+1));
```

Giving

```
q = integral(fun,0,inf)

q =

3.1416
```

This overview article on Array vs. Matrix operations may be of interest, outlining all element-wise `.` type functions.
https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html

Specifically, see these help articles on multplication and right-array division to give you an idea: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html, https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html

Comment: The period/dot, `.`,  specifies _element-wise_ operations.

Comment: Thanks @Jørgen, I quickly realised the same bad wording and have corrected myself

Comment: @Will The link you pointed to is not entirely correct.  That points to the fixed point toolbox.  I have corrected to point to the actual links you are looking for (cue Star War's reference).

Comment: @rayryeng You're correct, I didn't read it thoroughly enough. I've now also sought out the overview article on Matrix vs. Array operations and added that link.